# Serilog not logging to file ASP.Net Core 3.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, serilog, blazor-server-side

I am trying to log to a file using `Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0` in my `WebAssembly` `Blazor` applications.

I have used Nicholas Blumhardt's blog entry here;

[Setting up Serilog in ASP.NET Core 3.2](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/)

In my `Program.cs` of the blazor.server application I have the following code;

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter())
        .WriteTo.File(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(), "/logs/log.ndjson")
        .CreateLogger();
        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }


    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

I have the following packages installed;

`Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0`
`Serilog.Sinks.File 4.1.0`
`Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.5.0`

(I include the MSSql Sink reference for completness as my next step is to look to log to a db).

However, when I debug locally and also when I publish to a server in IIS no log.ndjson is being created?

Comment: which path are you checking the file? how are you running the application?

Comment: @viveknuna I've searched the directory for the `log.ndjson` and it turns up with nothing. I assumed it would be created int he root folder?

Comment: it will create in the project directory if you are running from visual studio

Comment: fixed it, thanks for pointing that out. It was actually creating the logs in the root C:\ changing to `./logs/log.ndjson` resolved the issue. Thanks @viveknuna !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the file will be created in the project directory if you run from visual studio. so it all depends how are you running the application. so you have to change the path for file.